# Cannot install augpy

Tags: python

I'm getting this error while installing [augpy](http://augpy.readthedocs.io/)

```
C:\Users\fiona>python -m pip install augpy
Collecting augpy
  Using cached augpy-1.0.0a1.tar.gz (440 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\fiona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\fiona\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-er_sei2q\\augpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\fiona\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-er_sei2q\\augpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\fiona\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-navhxm3e'
         cwd: C:\Users\fiona\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-er_sei2q\augpy\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\fiona\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-er_sei2q\augpy\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from generate_saturate_cast_cuh import generate_saturate_cast_cuh
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'generate_saturate_cast_cuh'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Anyone out there with a solution?

Comment: I tried everything and i get the same problem over and over again. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/itssmutnuri/AugPy/issues/1) on github hopefully it will get their attention.